# Find $f_{xy}(x,y)$ using the first principle

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} y\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} , &\text{if } (x,y) \ne (0,0);\\0,& \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}$

We need to find $f_{xy}(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$, based on the first principle. I proceed as the following -
$$f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f_y(\Delta x,0)-f_y(0,0)}{\Delta x}$$

To find the above,
$$f_y(\Delta x,0)=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{f_x(\Delta x,\Delta y)-f_x(\Delta x,0)}{\Delta y}=\lim_{\Delta y \to 0}\frac{\Delta y\frac{{\Delta x}^2-{\Delta y}^2}{{\Delta x}^2+{\Delta y}^2}}{\Delta y}=\lim_{\Delta y\to 0}\frac{{\Delta x}^2-{\Delta y}^2}{{\Delta x}^2+{\Delta y}^2}$$
Here the limit is clearly $1$ when $\Delta x $ doesn't tend to zero, But as it does, How should we use the first principle to evaluate $f_{xy}(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x\ne0,$ I agree:
$$f_y(x,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1.$$
But
$$f_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(0,y)}y=-1.$$
Therefore, $x\mapsto f_y(x,0)$ is not continuous at $0$. A fortiori, $f_{x,y}(0,0)$ does not exist.